# Scrollbars For Iframes

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe, scrollbar

I have used an iframe to scale up my webpage. The problem is the scrollbar for my iframe does not allow me to scroll down the whole page. I am only able to view half of my page. How do I increase or change the size of the scrollbar slider so that I am able to scroll further down my page?

Here is my code: 
**CSS:**

```
#wrapper { 
width: 100%; 
height: 100%; 
padding: 0; 
overflow: scroll;
}

#scaled-frame { 
width: 100%; 
height: 100%; 
border: 0px; 
}

#scaled-frame {
zoom: 1.30;
transform-origin: 50% 0%;
-moz-transform: scale(1.30);
-moz-transform-origin: 50% 0%;
-o-transform: scale(1.30);
-o-transform-origin: 50% 0;
-webkit-transform: scale(1.30);
-webkit-transform-origin: 50% 0%;
}

@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
#scaled-frame  { zoom: 1;  
 }
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<body bgcolor="#000000">
    <div id="wrapper"><iframe id="scaled-frame" src="videos_large.html"></iframe></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your transform-origin styles.

Answer (score 0):

my approach would be to remove the overflow of the `#wrapper`, and instead apply the overflow to the `#scaled-frame` like so:

```
#wrapper { width: 100%; height: 100%; padding: 0; overflow: hidden; }
#scaled-frame { width: 100%; min-height: 100% height: auto; border: 0px;overflow: hidden; overflow-y:scroll;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `overflow: scroll;` in CSS.

**HTML Markup**

```
<iframe class="iFrameScroll"><\iframe>
```

**CSS**

```
.iFrameScroll {
overflow: scroll;
}
```

You shouldn't have this problem with iframe, unless there is a wrong code has been writing.

Comment: And remover the overflow from wrapper

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all,  I will try your solutions. I have made the wrapper bigger than the scaled frame, which seems to have done it for now, but I will give your solutions a go.